# Accessing textview of another View in Android

Tags: android, textview, view

I hope someone have answer to this. I have one View called main.xml, that view is using one more view list_item.xml and, like ataching some information to main.xml where is some list etc.. Now, in that list_item.xml I have TextView that I want to change color with change of its content... So I'm ok with getting content of that textview, but I cannot access to that textview to change color..Everything is happening in one activity..This is part of a code in that activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Zadaci se učitavaju...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //PROVERA KONEKCIJE
     CheckConnectivity check = new CheckConnectivity();
     Boolean conn = check.checkNow(this.getApplicationContext());
     if(conn == true){

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_OBAV);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>

    TextView tvv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prioritet);
    int num = 1;   
    String str = String.valueOf(num);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

        map.put(KEY_PROF, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PROF));
        map.put(KEY_PRE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRE));
        map.put(KEY_TXT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TXT));
        map.put(KEY_VRE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_VRE));
        map.put(KEY_PRI, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRI));
        map.put(KEY_ATA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ATA));
        menuItems.add(map);

        if((parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRI)).equalsIgnoreCase(str)){

            tvv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.somecolor);
            System.out.println((parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRI)).toString());

            }


    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_PROF, KEY_PRE, KEY_TXT, KEY_VRE, KEY_PRI, KEY_ATA}, new int[] {
                    R.id.profesor,R.id.vreme, R.id.tekst, R.id.predmet, R.id.prioritet, R.id.atachment });

    setListAdapter(adapter);






    }
```

And this is list_item.xml, where I need to access that textview called "prioritet":

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/bordo">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prioritet"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/bordot"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:background="@color/bordot"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Prioritet:"
            android:textColor="@color/bela"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/bordot"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Atachment:"
            android:textColor="@color/bela"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/atachment"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
            android:background="@color/bordot"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/crvena"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So, what I want is just, when is inside of textview "prioritet" number 1 to be one color of that textview, when is number 2 other and so on...
I know that I can not just access because of the view, that is main...I tried with inflating..didn't work..Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is tvv.setBackgroundColor giving the same results?

Comment: Thanks for replaying. Well, yes...If I define that textview tvv good, I mean without some error it doesn't do anything..like it doesn't have access to that textview.

Answer (score 0):

If prioritet is inside list_item.xml, you should call findViewById to that ViewGroup reference and not against the same activity (it may be looking for that view just in main.xml).

Following the later, if there is a "prioritet" view for each item, it does not make sense to just finding it once. As you are on the onCreate and the list hasn't been populated yet, you have to make changes in each item, and that is why you should implement your own version of ListAdapter:

By extending ArrayAdapter and overriding

```
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

for example.

There you may do the following:

```
TextView tvv = null;
View v = convertView;
if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    tvv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.prioritet);
}
// do what you want with tvv..
// If we have to decide following KEY_PRI..
Map<String,String> currentMap = getItem(position);
/* remember that in this adapter you will only have the List of maps..
   nothing else so you must check only against the current map.. */
if (currentMap.get(KEY_PRI).equals(someNum)) {
    // now do what you want    
}
```

If you have doubts about how to do your own ArrayAdapter extension for all this, you can do the following:

```
public class MyMapListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Map<String,String>> { 
    public RoomListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Map<String,String>> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //... here comes the previously mentioned code
    }
```

}

and you may use it as..

```
ListView mapsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id_in_main);
MyMapListViewAdapter listAdapter = new MyMapListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, hotel.getRooms());
//...
mapsList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: Awesome, tell us if that was the problem.

Comment: Ok, I have one question, that what I want to do with tvv, needs to happen inside if inside for, so inside this if((parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRI)).equalsIgnoreCase(str)){...........} How can I do that, can I actually?

Comment: mm if that will be each row dependent, you will have to do that in the adapter. The list of items that you set in the adapter's constructor (plus the arguments that you may add) will be the objects to use inside each row logic.. I've added some more code to make it more clear.